# ¿Como pongo el ejecutable de chrome en PATH? Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

sigo intentando abrir un navegador desde python, usando selenium. Este es el código :

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser=webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://facebook.com")
```

Me aparece este error :

```
WebDriverException: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see 
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Ya descargue el ejecutable de chromedriver pero no se a que se refiere con "PATH" supongo que es un archivo pero no se cual es.

Answer (score 2):

El *path* es la ruta de búsqueda, y suele ser una lista separada por comas de carpetas dónde se buscará el ejecutable. Este *path* se almacena en la [*variable de entorno*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_de_entorno) `PATH`.

Puedes ver su contenido saliendo a la línea de comandos y escribiendo

```
> path
```

Esto *imprimirá* el valor actual de la variable.

Para probar si realmente el *chromedriver* está en la RUTA, sal a la línea de comandos y escribe `chromedriver` (asumiendo que el ejecutable aún tiene ese nombre) y presiona <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Si aparece algo como `Starting ChromeDriver 2.15.322448`, el *PATH* está configurado de forma apropiada.

Otra alternativa, es no valerte del entorno e indicar una ruta completa:

```
  driver = webdriver.Chrome ('/ruta/a/chromedriver')
```

Por ejemplo:

```
  driver = webdriver.Chrome ("C:/Users/juan/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
```

Comment: Estoy intentando poner eso en la terminal, pero no me aparece nada. Creo que es porque estoy usando MacOSX. ¿Sabes como lo hago en este sistema?

Comment: Creo que es un pedazo algo importante de información que debiste incluir en tu pregunta.

Comment: Si quieres ver el valor de la variable de entorno en MacOS escribe `echo $PATH` en la línea de comandos.